# Data not getting displayed from fetching from an api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, ecmascript-6

First i declared an empy array inside states:

But Data is not getting displayed it is showing some error :

also it is show an error when setting state as

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')
```

and it is pointing towards the setState line
can someone solve this

Comment: you don't need JSON.stringify(jsonData) because it converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string. If you console.log(jsonStr) you will know what I mean, then you try to access the .course_title of a string.

Comment: Any update on this question ? Did my answer solve your problem ? If so please mark my answer as aceepted.

Answer (score 3):

I dont understand why you use JSON.stringify here

```
return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Because you already convert your data into json here

```
 return response.json();
```

Also calling API to get data is using `componentDidMount` life cycle hook. Try to change your code like this

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/"my end point in api"')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonStr) {
                this.setState({ CourseTitle: jsonStr.course_title });
            });
    }
```

Comment: hey tony i cant verify your answer is working or not i tried putting console.log but nothing was shown up . porpbably i think i couldnt use console.log in a right place can u please edit your code putting console.log or any other method such that i could verify the answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the official docs,componentWillMount is depreciated,try calling it in componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/"my end point in api"')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(jsonData) {
            return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
        })
        .then(function(jsonStr) {
            this.setState({ CourseTitle: jsonStr.course_title });
            alert(jsonStr.course_title);
        });

 }
```

And while printing ,put a condition like
console.log("printing",this.state.courseTitle?this.state.courseTitle:"not yet fetched")

Answer (score 0):

Not getting why are you fetching like mentioned in post instead of like this...

```
     componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/"my end point in api"')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonStr) {
                this.setState({ CourseTitle: jsonStr.course_title });
                alert(jsonStr.course_title);
            });
    }
```

and also console your data before rendering

And it's recommended to call api in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method as per official documentation of [Reactjs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

Try to follow the recommendations of others, change `componentWillMount` by `componentDidMount`.

Also, follow the recommendation of removing the `JSON.stringify(jsonData)` because you are converting the object in a string and after that, you are trying to access object properties (and they don't exist).

And finally, it is a common error in `JavaScript` to misunderstand what is the meaning of `this` in different contexts. For example, take a look at the next snippet:

```js
const obj = {
  say() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  },
  sayDelayed() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.toString());
    }, 500);
  }
};

obj.say();
obj.sayDelayed();
```

As you can observe, `this` inside the `setTimeout` is not referencing the object anymore and this is because [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem) is referencing another object (most probably `window` in non-strict mode).

In your case, `this` inside the `fetch` is not referencing the `class` anymore. Try to store the scope of the `class` in a variable before executing the `fetch` and use this variable instead of `this` to call `setState`. Check the next snippet:

```js
const obj = {
  fetch() {
    const myObject = this;
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(jsonStr) {
        console.log('wrong this', this.toString());
        console.log('right this', myObject.toString());
      });
  }
};

obj.fetch();
```

You need to refactor your code into something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const cls = this;
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/"my end point in api"')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonStr) {
            cls.setState({ CourseTitle: jsonStr.course_title });
        });
}
```